# Prove that $\frac{b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2+\cdots+b_n^2}{n}\geq2011$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Initially, only the integer $44$ is written on a board. An integer a on the
>   board can be re- placed with four pairwise different integers $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ such that the arithmetic mean $\frac{1}{4}(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)$ of the four new integers is equal to the number $a$. 
>   In a step we simultaneously replace all the integers on the board
>   in the above way. After $30$ steps we end up with $n = 4^{30}$ integers $b_1, b_2, . . . , b_n$ on the board. Prove that: $$\frac{b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2+\cdots+b_n^2}{n}\geq2011$$

I've spent some days trying to solve this problem, but I've no idea of how to figure it out. Any idea?

Comment: Please write down what you have tried, in its current state your question can be subject to closure.

Comment: The integers can be positive or negative.

Comment: @Matteo Easy to show that it's $\geq1936.$ :)

Comment: @Matteo Yes, I misread the inequality sign at first glance.

Comment: Just a thought.  It looks like the smallest number we can make after one step is $1938.5$ by writing $42,43,45,46.$  This is an increase of $2.5$ over the original $1936$.  If we can show that the increase must always be at least $2.5$, then $30$ steps would make at least $1936+75=2011.$

Answer (score 3):

We replace an integer $x$ by the $4$ distinct integers $x-a, x-b, x-c, x-d$ where $a+b+c+d = 0.$  Consider $$(x-a)^2+ (x-b)^2 +(x-c)^2+ (x-d)^2-4x^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2.$$  This is minimized, with value $10$, when $$\{a,b,c,d\}=\{-1,-2,1,2\}$$

If you apply this observation to the problem, you will see that there is a minimum increase of $2.5$ at each step. After $30$ steps, the average of the squares must be at least $$44^2+30\cdot2.5=2011.$$

Comment: +1..........................